# moving files to folder

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to move all files with the extension .RCS into a directory called Archives as below

```
move C:\Users\abs\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\*.RCS    
C:\Users\abs\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\Archives
```

but the above doesn't work, also one step better would be if I can also move another file extension called .CSO as well .RCS

Answer (score 0):

I didn't put the double quotes. Newbie mistake